# Why is FormController expecting a name in my form to inject itself?

Tags: angularjs

I noticed that only if a form has a name attribute like this:

```
<form name="myform"></form>
```

Then I can get hold of the FormController like this:

```
var form = $('form')[0];
var formController = $(form).scope().myform;
```

What is the deal with this pattern? Why does't Angular simply put a "**formController**" in the form's scope - like its common when implementing custom directives?

I am curious mainly to understand if this is some pattern I should expect in other cases and if I should follow while implementing my own directives.

Thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity, where did you read you can get a FormController by just having a form with a name attribute? Could you provide your source? Maybe I can help you after this.Thanks!

Comment: See this documentation for FormController (go to the Arguments description): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form. Also, here is an example usage (see bottom of the blog): http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/06/10/model-options-and-pristine-forms-in-angularjs.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you mention in the comments state that when using the name attribute, the FormController is published onto the current scope. This means that to access it from your controller you only need to do `$scope.myFormsName`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.9" data-semver="1.5.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <form name="myForm">
      <input name="birthdate" type="text" />
    </form>
    {{ myForm | json }}
  </body>

</html>
```

And in the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.myForm; // here's the FormController
}])
```

When implementing your own directives the approach is different. For this you should use the `require` property of directives, which is explained in depth [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). With this property, you can tell Angular that your directive requires (can be an optional requirement) said controller, and it will provide it in the link function:

```
mod.directive('crudForm', ['CrudTemplatesDir', function (tplDir) {
        return {
            scope: {
                fields: '=*',
                record: '=',
                listsOfValues: '=*?'
            },
            require: '^^form', // Can be a string for 1 or array of strings for multiple requirements
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: tplDir + 'form.tpl.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, requiredController){
                // Required controller is the one you defined in 'require' as a string. If you defined an array, this will be an array of controllers
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Andres, thanks for your response. I am however trying to access the formcontroller properties from somewhere else in my JS (can be anywhere if you think about it). And my question is why is it using the name property and not a standard "formController" property (like I believe all custom directive implementations do usually).

Comment: When you say "anywhere" do you mean outside angularjs code?

Comment: No, no, from any controller code for example. The form may not be in the same visual tree, so I might have to find it (with jquery selector) and then do the necessary.

Comment: Can you give a precise example of what you are trying to achieve? The idea of the scope is that it provides access to things inside of it, if you want it available for all your app then you'd have to set it on `$rootScope` either by placing the form element outside of any other scope-creating directive, or manually with the `$rootScope` service.

Comment: Andres, I think we are still not on the same page here. Things work fine now. I am able to get hold of the "FormController". I am only curious about the difference in pattern followed by the Angular's form directive implementation compared to several other directives I have seen.

Comment: I wouldn't know the exact reason they made it that way, but since the form directive is somewhat unique and very specific to user inputs, it's possible that eventually people started needing things from it in their scope and it was added. I haven't found any concrete explanation on the reason for this thou.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), we can see angular actually doesn't expect at all a name, but if you do so, it'll append the form object to the `$scope`.

**Form's directive** is very specific to forms elements, and it's almost sure we are going to need to get them whithin the controller, in many possible places (when submitting it, for example). So I guess this was an attempt to make things easier for us.

**Other directives** (`ngClick`, `ngIf`, `ngClass`...) are too broad, you could use them with any element (div, tag, img, i...), so it wouldn't even make sense to automatically bind everything  to `$scope`, it'd get unnecessarily polluted, and we would probably not even need them. If we needed, we could bind them by ourselves (much better).

I don't know if it's a pattern at all, but if you had to build a directive, depending on its purpose, you could automatically bind objects to `$scope` if you knew developers would probably need them (because it's very specific). Or you could follow their approach and bind depending on some attribute, like `id`, `name`, `data-my-attribute`, and so on.

Comment: Alisson, thanks for the response. Yes, name is optional. But, my question was why is Angular expecting us to provide a name attribute, rather than simply adding a "formController" object into the $scope - like I believe all directive/controller implementations do usually.

Comment: @praveen_r you're welcome, let's try to understanding it. What would be the purpose of simply adding a `formController` object into the `$scope`? Would it hold a list of forms, rather than just binding that forms directly to `$scope`?